# How to get the return value of <select> that uses NiceForm Plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I used a plugin called niceform [NiceForms](https://github.com/emblematiq/Niceforms/) and it changes my form elements to `<a>` and `<li>` tags. I'm having hard time getting the return value of the selected item.

please see my **jsbin** here: http://jsbin.com/ufoxuc

```
$(function(){

    $("#gender").change(function () {
       alert($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Please help. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is simple, juste select the child of your select and access to the value

```
$("#gender").change(function () {
   var value = $("#gender option:selected").val();
   alert(value);
});
```

Hope that it helps

Comment: problem of this it's not the child of select. A separate elements are being created.

Answer (score 0):

Actulally there is no select, they are just `<div>` styled as `<select>` so the `change()` function never fires, are you sure thatthe plugin doesn't offer a hook to listen to the `change()` event?

Comment: Yes, I know. I just did that to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure if there's a hook but If there are I can't find it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pennf0lio the plugin overrides the onchange event, look at the `Implementing a Jump Menu` voice of the readme. My personal advice: choose another plugin, this is not the correct way to handle things, IMHO

Comment: thanks for the personal advice. I've also been thinking of that. But there's already a lot of work done around this plugin to change for a new one. Do you think it's possible to just listen on the changes of the elements that were generated? eg. inside <ul> or <a>.

Comment: @Pennf0lio that's difficult, because the generated element don't fire the "change" event...the only way is doing like the plugin suggest, i'm afraid

Comment: Thanks, will try to investigate for further solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

Edit the original niceforms.js and replace following line (probably line number 544):

```
el.lnk._onclick = el.onclick || function () {};

//WITH following

el.lnk._onclick = el.onclick || function () {
    if (this.ref.oldClassName.indexOf("NFOnChange") > -1){
        this.ref.options[this.pos].selected = "selected";
        //Call the original onchange event
        this.ref.onchange();
    }
};
```

After doing this, you need to add the NFOnChange class to your select tag, like this:

```
<select size="1" name="gender" id="gender" class="NFOnChange" onchange="yourFunction()">
```

Thats how i managed to make it work. Hope it helps

Comment: hmm, this would be my last option. I'm trying to avoid editing the plugin. Thanks :)